# Windows 10 NTFS permissions for Azure AD account

Tags: windows-10, office365, azure-activedirectory

I joined Windows 10 to Azure Active Directory and signed in with my Azure AD email address and password.

`whoami` returns `AzureAD\<Full Name>` and the NTFS permissions of the user profile folder also show the folder owner as `AzureAD\<Full Name>`. The user has a profile folder called `Users\<Full Name>`.

However I am unable to select this user at all in the `Select a principal` dialog when I want to grant permissions to other folders. What is the correct syntax for Azure AD users?

When using just Azure AD accounts, there are no user accounts at all in in `Local Users` (unlike a Microsoft Account which is linked to a local user).

Comment: Related, possibly useful: http://superuser.com/questions/982336/how-do-i-add-azure-active-directory-user-to-local-administrators-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions show the actual domain name, but the same issue still exists.  You can use Powershell to set the permissions.

```
    $dir = get-item -Path 'C:\users\jshelby\Desktop\testdir\'    
    $acl = $dir.GetAccessControl('Access')
    $username = 'domain\username'
    $AccessRights = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($username,'Modify','ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit','None','Allow')
    $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRights)
    Set-Acl -path $dir -AclObject $acl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this short PowerShell example which is tested on Windows 10, build 1809, which is Azure Active Directory registered. Please modify $path to your local folder, and for $permission you can use any Azure AD user, but username must be in AzureAD\upn format (example AzureAD\smith@company.com)

```
$path = "C:\myfolder"
$permission = "AzureAD\myuser@mydomain.com","FullControl","Allow"
(Get-Acl $path).SetAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission)) | Set-Acl $path
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything. No error message either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in Jesus's script.

```
Set-Acl : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:6 char:19
+     Set-Acl -path $Path -AclObject $Acl
+                   ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

This is an updated script:

```
    $dir = get-item -Path 'C:\users\jshelby\Desktop\testdir\'    
    $acl = $dir.GetAccessControl('Access')
    $username = 'domain\username'
    $AccessRights = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Username,'Modify','ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit','None','Allow')
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRights)
    Set-Acl -path $dir -AclObject $Acl
```

Also, I tried this first on PowerShell Core. `$dir.GetAccessControl()` does not seem to exist in PowerShell Core, only Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

@Hrvoje Kusulja's answer has the right concept but has a bug as `SetAccessRule` doesn't return the ACL object that it was called on.

The fix is to assign the ACL to a variable so that after `SetAccessRule` is called we still have a reference to it to pass to `Set-ACL`.

```
$path = "C:\myfolder"
$permission = "AzureAD\myuser@mydomain.com","FullControl","Allow"
$acl = (Get-Acl $path)
$acl.SetAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission)) 
$acl | Set-Acl $path
```